# Displaying a Default View (User Control) on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm building an application that will have a Dashboard, Customers, and Job Tickets Views. When I start my app, I want to display the view for the Dashboard. I'm trying to use MVVM throughout the application so I don't want to design my Dashboard on the MainWindow.

This is my MainWindow at launch. When I start the app, I would like for the Dashboard View to be shown by default where the white space is. I have already set that area of the screen for the content control, I'm just wondering how to display this particular View by default without having to click the Button for it after startup.
[image: l]
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `UserControl`...

Comment: How would I bind this UserControl to show on my MainWindow at launch, and every time the Dashboard button is clicked?

Comment: Maybe not completely clear question then. Are you mean the separate `Window` as child View or Dashboard layout? Provide an example please e.g. CJM part or Userstory. Add some guessing words to the question (edit it) to make it more focused.

Comment: [this](https://gyazo.com/6fa4296371a2323aad0425d9e5a602af) is my MainWindow at launch. When I start the app, I would like for the Dashboard View to be shown by default (where the white space is) I have already set that area of the screen for the content control, I'm just wondering how to display this particular View by default without having to click the Button for it after startup.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no suggestions at the moment but guessings and don't want mislead you. I'll think twice and maybe later will add something here. Additionally it would be great if you consider adding above comment (or its part) to the question content. You may attach the image there too (but use internal StackOverflow functionality to do that). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So from what I understood your problem is how to show the "Dashboard" view automatically at start up.

As @aepot said in the comments you first need to be able to show the "Dashboard" view at your need. This can be done creating the "Dashboard" view inside a `UserControl` (the same will happends for the "Customers" and the "Job Tickets" views).
These UserControls works the same way as a `Window` (for what concern this problem).

The UserControls will serve as source for a `ContentPresenter`.

Now there are two options:

- a `UserControl` property in the ViewModel (notifying its state change using `INotifyPropertyChanged`) binded to the `ContentPresenter`.
- Setup a more complex solution (maybe with the help of `Messenger`, and other utility patterns) in which you move the previous pattern inside the `MainWindow` code-behind.

Either case you would just simply set the property in the constructor (ViewModel in the first case, code-behind in the second).

It is not a real solution but I hope I have been helpful anyway.